# Removes all but the first occurrence of a given char in the string

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in C# and I'm stuck at this problem.

```
  string original = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ ";  
  string desired_output = "foo bar foo $ bar foo bar";
```

I found a rough code but the result is not good.

Can you help me solve the problem?

Here is my code:

```
  string s = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ ";

  char ch = '$';

  for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
  {
      if (s[i] == ch)
      {
          s = s.Substring(0, i) +
          s.Substring(i + 1);
          break;
      }
   }
   
   for (int i = s.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
   {            
       if (s[i] == ch)
       {
           s = s.Substring(0, i) +
           s.Substring(i + 1);
           break;
       }
   }
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The output I receive is `foo bar foo bar $ foo bar`.

Comment: What answer are you getting?

Comment: @BogdanNetan, Did you look String.Replace method?

Comment: @Arshad not yet

Comment: @ShaiCohen    foo bar foo  bar $ foo bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string original = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ "; 
string desired_output = "foo bar foo $ bar foo bar"; 

string result = original; 
int index = original.IndexOf("$")+1;    
if (index > 0) 
{
    result = (original.Substring(0, index)  + original.Substring(index).Replace("$", "")).Replace("  ", " ").Trim();
}

Console.WriteLine(desired_output == result);
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/I3lVua

---

Or:

```
string original = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ "; 
string desired_output = "foo bar foo $ bar foo bar"; 

var buffer = original.ToCharArray();
bool found = false;
int dest = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
{
    if (buffer[i] != '$' || !found)
    {
       buffer[dest] = buffer[i];
       dest++;
    }
    if (buffer[i] == '$') found = true;
}

var result = new string(buffer, 0, dest).Replace("  ", " ").Trim();
    
Console.WriteLine(desired_output == result);
```

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/iVtw8E

Notice for both solutions there is an issue with the extra spacing, hence the extra `Replace()` and `Trim()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep only the first $ then the first thing you would need to do is use that first for loop to find the first $ and make the latter substring until the end of the main string. Once you've done that, use the [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) function to replace all other $ in that substring. Then just combine the first part of the substring and the cleaned second part and you will get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 2 for loops for that. One is enough. Just copy all chars into a `StringBuilder`, except, if the char is the desired character (`$`) and it was already copied once before. A single bool flag suffices to accomplish that.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static string RemoveAllButFirst(char c, string s) {
            var first = true;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (char x in s) {
                if (c == x) {
                    if (first) {
                        sb.Append(x);
                        first = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.Append(x);
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string original = "foo bar foo $ bar $ foo bar $ ";
            System.Console.WriteLine(original);
            System.Console.WriteLine(RemoveAllButFirst( '$', original));
        }
    }
}
```